# Sequence of non-collinear integer points.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is a question from a British Olympiad, I've completed the first 3 but this one had me rather stumped.

> Given two points $P$ and $Q$ with integer coordinates, we say that $P$ sees $Q$ if the line segment $PQ$ contains no other points with integer coordinates. An n-loop is a sequence of $n$ points $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$, each with integer coordinates, such that the following conditions hold:
>
> a) $P_i$ sees $P_{i+1}$ for for $1≤i≤n−1$, and $P_n$ sees $P_1$
>
> b) No $P_i$ sees any  $P_j$ apart from those in (a);
>
> c) No three points lie on a straight line.
>
> Does there exist a 100 loop?

My first instinct is that the 100-loop has could be a polygon of 100 edges, none of which parallel. It seems like the polygon has to be convex too.

I also conjecture that if $P_i$ sees $P_{i+1}$ then $gcd(x_i-x_{i+1},y_i-y_{i+1})=1$. The curve $y=x^2$ also seems to satisfy the condition for integer $x$ between 0 and 99 but again I can't seem to prove it.

If I can prove that conjecture about the gcd then that should be sufficient. I am having issues with doing so though. Any hints? Chinese Remainder theorem maybe?

I am also hoping to take this problem further if possible and explore for which possible $n$ does a loop exist so help in that regard is very much appreciated.

I must insist on full solutions being at the very least under a spoiler tag, I was after hints and starting points to explore first and foremost.

Comment: 4-loop: (0,0), (1,2), (2,2), (4,-1).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yeah 4-loops can work. Another example is (-1,0) (0,-1) (1,0) (0,1) or |x| + |y| =1

Comment: It seems that gcd conjecture (even in “iff” form) is just a reformulation, so to prove it you have just to see this, clearly understand what it means. You can do it. :-)

Comment: I think we have to finish that. So, it seems the following. For arbitrary $n$ we already have a set 
$\{P_0,P_2,\dots, P_n\}$ of points of the parabola such that $P_i=(i,i^2)$ for each $i$ and 
$P_i$ sees $P_j\ne P_i$ iff $|i-j|=1$. So we  have to place just one point $P_{n+1}$ which sees $P_0$ and $P_n$, but does not see other $P_i$. We shall search $P_{n+1}$ in form $(-1,N)$. Then $P_{n+1}$ sees $P_0$.

Comment: In order to $P_{n+1}$ does not see $P_i$ with $1\le i\le n-1$ we have 
$$1<\text{gcd} (i+1,N-i^2)= \text{gcd} (i+1,N+i^2+2i+1-i^2)= \text{gcd} (i+1,N+i).$$ So we can put $N=n!+1$. But there is a small problem: we need that $P_{n+1}$  see $P_{n}$, that is $1=\text{gcd} (n+1,N-n^2)=\text{gcd} (n+1,n!)$. If $n+1$ is prime, we are done. In the opposite case we should find an other point $P_{n+1}$.